# Incorrect Cyrillic (Macedonian) glyphs in Computer Modern

Tags: cyrillic, computer-modern

Does anyone have any idea why the glyphs for [Ѓѓ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gje) and [Ќќ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kje) that come with Computer Modern are wrong, i.e. they have a grave accent instead of an acute one? Is there a way to fix this?

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
Аа Бб Вв Гг Дд \textcolor{red}{Ѓѓ} Ее Жж Зз Ѕѕ Ии Јј Кк Лл Љљ\\
Мм Нн Њњ Оо Пп Рр Сс Тт \textcolor{red}{Ќќ} Уу Фф Хх Цц Чч\\
Џџ Шш
\end{document}
```

[image: Macedonian glyphs]

(I am using TeX Live 2015 as my distribution, but the situation has been this way since I began using TeX)

Comment: Bugs get fixed quicker if you report them:-) Sorry about that, I've checked a fix in to the latex sources so it should be fixed at the next latex update (not sure when that will be yet)

Comment: Note that those Macedonian letters are not really supported by any of the Cyrillic encodings T2A, T2B and T2C, and they will always realized with a superimposed accent, so making hyphenation impossible past them. This might be a problem or not, depending on their frequency; as they seem to appear only in loanwords, the problem may be minor.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks; I never realized that was the case. This is only true for LaTeX, right? (i.e. not true for XeLaTeX)

Comment: @d125q No, because there are independent slots for those characters. However this is academic, as there are no hyphenation patterns for Macedonian, as far as I know, nor it is supported by `babel` or `polyglossia`. Can it share patterns with Bulgarian?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The fix has been pushed upstream as of today (`tlmgr update --self --all`). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @d125q sorry it took so long!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

---

Fixed in the `inputenc` shipped with `LaTeX2e 2015/01/01 patch level 1`.

---

This isn't directly related to cm but looks like a bug in the core latex utf8 mapping, this fixes it for now

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0403}{\@tabacckludge'\CYRG}%
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0453}{\@tabacckludge'\cyrg}%
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{040C}{\@tabacckludge'\CYRK}%
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{045C}{\@tabacckludge'\cyrk}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Аа Бб Вв Гг Дд \textcolor{red}{Ѓѓ} Ее Жж Зз Ѕѕ Ии Јј Кк Лл Љљ\\
Мм Нн Њњ Оо Пп Рр Сс Тт \textcolor{red}{Ќќ} Уу Фф Хх Цц Чч\\
Џџ Шш
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, David. Could you please point me to some references so that I can read some more about this?

Comment: @d125q `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` comes from `inputenc`  see `texdoc inputenc`

Answer (score 3):

If you compile with `Xe/LuaLaTeX`, you can use `Computer Modern Unicode`, which doesn't have this problem:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
Аа Бб Вв Гг Дд \textcolor{red}{Ѓѓ} Ее Жж Зз Ѕѕ Ии Јј Кк Лл Љљ\\
Мм Нн Њњ Оо Пп Рр Сс Тт \textcolor{red}{Ќќ} Уу Фф Хх Цц Чч\\
Џџ Шш
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks; I was aware of this, but found CM Unicode to have some subtle differences as compared to the "classic" one (or it might have just been `microtype` issues; I don't know).